# SQLite Query not returning any records

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm executing an SQLite query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT hotel.cityName, hotel.hotelName, hotel.roomName, hotel.roomCode, hotel.roomType, hotel.maxPax FROM hotel WHERE ( hotel.cityName = 'Adelaide' OR hotel.cityName = 'Brisbane' OR hotel.cityName = 'Canberra' ) AND hotel.maxPax < 200 AND hotel.maxPax >= 100 AND ( hotel.roomType = 'Boardroom' )"
```

against a database table called "hotel" created from XML, with the following headings (according to DDMS):

```
id (INT)
cityName (TEXT)
hotelName (TEXT)
roomCode (TEXT)
roomName (TEXT)
roomType (TEXT)
maxPax (INT)
```

Each time I run the query:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase ( );
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery ( selectQuery, null );
```

cursor.getCount() returns 0.

I have checked the actual data, and this query should definitely return data. Why does cursor.getCount() return 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java code looks fine, I am guessing the problem is with your SQL. When I have such problems, I often re-create the DB contents in Firefox's [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) or [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and then take the query and start removing things from the WHERE clase until I get results.

Comment: Thx for the help. Managed to get it working using Firefox's SQLite Manager (excellent resource!). It was a stupid typo on my part :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the 'query' method ([Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))

```
db.query("hotel", null, "(cityName = ? OR cityName = ? OR cityName = ?) AND maxPax < 200 AND maxPax >= 100 AND roomType = ?", new String[] {"Adelaide", "Brisbane", "Canberra", "Boardroom"}, null, null, null);
```

If it doesn't work, extract the database and test the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try assign your database variable to a SQLiteOpenHelper. I don't really know if a rather arbitrary `this` would have `getWritableDatabase()` method.

```
SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new SQLiteOpenHelper()
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the quotes around the String :( the actual selectQuery does have quotes around it, I'll amend the question.

Comment: @user2313303 changed my answer.